# Does terraform provide a way to pull all private subnets in a VPC data source?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I'm writing some Terraform that scans many VPCs, and I'd like to use a data source to pull only the private subnets of each one in order to attach them to a transit gateway.

Is there anyway to do that without knowing in advance which ones are private?

If I could find all subnets in a VPC that are not attached to an internet gateway using a data source, I think that should suffice, is there any way to do this in Terraform?

Comment: I think you would have to use the `aws_route_table` data source https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/route_table#gateway_id to find all the private route tables first, and then work backwards from there (through the `association_ids`) to get to the private subnets. I'm not posting an answer because I'm not 100% sure that would even work. It's usually MUCH easier to do this sort of thing if you have some good tags on your resources in AWS already, then you can just filter the subnets by tags.

Comment: Good idea Mark, I'll give that a go.  I had a feeling it would take several steps